# Vim - how do I map tabedit command to enable cycling through file names?

Tags: vim, user

I use the command `:tabe **/<file-name-pattern>` all the time to open files in the current directory and subdirs in a new tab in vim. The command enables toggling through similar file names until I find the one I'm looking for. I wanted to map it to a user command such that I'll have less to type, but am kinda new to vim commands and thought I'd ask for help. Here's what I could come up with (mapped to TT):

```
:command -nargs=1 TT :tabe **/<args>
```

The idea is mimic the functionality of the above and to type `:TT <file-name-pattern>` and then toggle with  key until the desired file is found. This, uh, didn't work. Any idea how to make this happen? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-complete=file` to the command:

> :command -nargs=1 -complete=file TT :tabe **/args

See "`:help :command-complete`".